# Applying SSR / social media sharing to selected routes in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

We made a late decision to implement social media sharing for Angular 7 project. As a first step of the re-write I wish to dynamically update social media tags for a particular route only ('/post/').

I am able to apply SSR on '/post/' using app.use in the server.ts file:

```
app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { }); // ignore api requests

app.use('/post/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
}); // successfully serves SSR content on '/post/' but client side rendering fails to take over. 

app.get('*', (req, res) => console.log('Other routes')) // 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' error
```

I am running off localhost:4200 for both server and client - spinning up the SSR node server with `npm run serve:ssr`, and spin up the client side with `ng serve`.

I am unsure the best way to handle requests for different routes. How can I tell Node to skip other routes and to spin up Angular on the client side? Currently it returns 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' error on other routes and only provides SSR content for '/posts/' (no client side rendering).

Comment: Are you using nginx or any other reverse proxy when not in dev environment?

Comment: Hi for client slide you add the path of pages to render? i think for understand your problem we need more info about your package.json and server.ts etc...